# How to plug in a variable of a multivariable x limit (ML) when fixing the others?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

For instance, if you have
the function $f(x,y)=\frac{2xy-2y}{x^2+y^2-2x+1}$, and

a two-variables limit

L := $\lim_{\substack{x\to 1 \\ y\to 0}}\frac{2xy-2y}{x^2+y^2-2x+1}$

and you want to **fix x=y**;  How do you proceed?

What I did is shown as it follows:

$\lim_{\substack{y\to 1 \\ y\to 0}}\frac{2y^2-2y}{y^2+y^2-2y+1}$ =  $\lim_{\substack{y\to 1 \\ y\to 0}}\frac{2y^2-2y}{2y^2+-2y+1}$

Here is my problem: I have a limit with y approaching to  two different values y=1 and y=0, What should I do? Did I make it wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah this doesn't make any sense, as you point out. You can't fix $x=y$ and then limit to a point $(1,0)$ that isn't on the line $x=y$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use that $$(x-1)^2+y^2\geq 2|x-1||y|$$